# How to extract view DDL on Firebird

Tags: view, firebird, ddl, firebird2.5

I need to get the DLL or the SELECT Statement used on a view from my DB. How can I get this?

My Firebird version: 2.5

Comment: Most DB administration tools (ie Flamerobin for Firebird) have "view source" option for objects - use that. Or you can use the `isql` command line tool which ships with Firebird to extract metadata (see the manual for exact syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to obtain the select statement of the view is to use:

```sql
select rdb$view_source
from rdb$relations
where rdb$relation_name = '<your view name>'
```

Note that the name is case sensitive, and object names that can be used unquoted must be uppercase here.

The `rdb$view_source` column only contains the part after the `as`-clause of the `create view`-statement (the select, and maybe the `with check option` clause).

Note that some application suppliers will sometimes remove the view source, in that case there is no real way to get back the original DDL, except by decompiling the binary compiled form in `rdb$view_blr`. I don't have experience with that.

Tools like Flame Robin also provides ways to obtain the DDL: expand the view tab, right click on the view, select properties and then tab DDL. Note that this has the same restrictions as above: if the view source was removed, it won't be available.

In ISQL you can use:

```
show view <your view name>;
```

Again: the same limitation applies.

You can also use ISQL to extract the full DDL of the entire database with

```
isql -ex -u sysdba -p password localhost:<path to your db>
```

But again, if the view source has been deleted, this won't help you.